# Can't git add . it shows warning: could not open the directory

Tags: git, warnings, addition, commit

I'm new to programming and eager to learn it, I have issue when save changes from Visual Code to github. I have edited the file on Gemfile, gemfile.lock and routes.rb on VSCode. But when I save it to github by typing `git add .`. It didn't work multiple times. Idk if I missed the step or what, but it always showed the warning. Also the git add  I added before is gone on the added list. Please help, I can't continue the lesson. Thank you.

```
xxx-MacBook-Air:~ userxxx$ git add --ignore-errors --force .
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application Support/MobileSync/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application Support/CallHistoryTransactions/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Saved Application State/com.vsco.vscokeys1.savedState/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.flashplayer.installmanager.savedState/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Saved Application State/com.bitrock.appinstaller.savedState/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Library/IdentityServices/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Messages/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/HomeKit/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Mail/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Safari/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Suggestions/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.VoiceMemos/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.Home/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Containers/com.apple.stocks/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/PersonalizationPortrait/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Metadata/com.apple.IntelligentSuggestions/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Cookies/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Caches/com.apple.safaridavclient/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Caches/com.apple.HomeKit.configurations/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory 'Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/': Operation not permitted
```

I expect can add changes to my github.

Comment: Hello Batman and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just dumping a large error message like this is not so helpful to others trying to understand your problem.  Instead, you should show us the exact series of Git commands which led to this situation.

Comment: thank you for review. Should I put the command from the git init ? sorry i'm very newbie.

Comment: It seems you type your command in a wrong catalog. Try to type ```ls -ah``` to find **.git** floder, where your repo's root is. And try ```git add .``` again.
If not, paste the catalog of your repo and the command you type may help us analyze.

Comment: I think you are also new to version control systems. Could you show us how did you clone repository?

Answer (score 2):

The error says, that git doesn't have permission to read from some paths it shouldn't have access to, because they are protected parts of the OS only an admin can access.

You are executing the git command in the home directory of your user. For the `git add` command to work, you have to execute it in the directory of the git repository. If your repo is in fact your home directory, that is really not a good idea and you should change it immediately. You should have **one repository per project.** Git will save all files and file changes in that and all subdirectories to the repository, which is not good if the repo is your home directory.

Comment: What about if I do like to track any change in my Mac

Comment: @Oliamster don't use git ;) it was not made for that purpose and you will probably run into some severe issues